# React JS - Return response of Fetched Json

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

Probably going to kick myself once I work this out, I'm having trouble parsing fetched Json, I have got as far as logging the results but have forgotten how to drill further into the json, believe I need to reference the keys of the returned arrays but would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

My goal is loop through the .name of each array using .map

**React Component**

```
// Uses react-fetch to retrive json from swapi
class Api extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
      <Fetch url="http://swapi.co/api/people/">
        <ApiResponse />
      </Fetch>
    )
  }
}

// Return results, having trouble digging further that .results (see Json below)
class ApiResponse extends React.Component{
  render(){
    console.log(this.props.results)
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 classType="character-name">{this.props.results/*This is where im stuck*/}</h1>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
[Object, Object]
0:Object
    gender:"male"
    height:"172"
    homeworld:"http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"
    name:"Luke Skywalker"
    __proto__:Object
0:Object
    gender:"male"
    height:"172"
    homeworld:"http://swapi.co/api/planets/1/"
    name:"Han Solo"
    __proto__:Object
length:2
__proto__
:Array[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the array and return jsx like this:

```
return (
  <ul>
    {this.props.results.map((user) =>
      <li key={user.name}>
        <h1 classType="character-name">{user.name}</h1>
        <p>{user.height}</p>
      </li>
    )}
  </ul>
);
```

Comment: I get an adjacent elements error from this, could you explain how the .map works here?

Comment: Oops, you probably need to return a single element in the `.map`. I've updated my answer. The map loops over the array and for each iteration adds a JSX element to the returned array. React handles rendering the array of JSX elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
render: function (){
    if (this.props.results) {
      return (
         {this.props.results.map(function(obj, index){
            return (
              <div key={index}>
                <h1 className="character-name">{obj.name}</h1> 
              </div>
            );
         })}
      )
    } else {
      return (<div></div>)
    }
  }
```